# Firefox history is only going back a month?

Tags: firefox, history

My firefox history is only showing just over a months worth of history.  I actually have history before that because if I type into the address bar it will bring up things I have searched for months ago, but even with the exact search term or website name, they don't appear in the history viewer :/.

Comment: If I remember correctly, history and the things you've typed in to the search bar are stored separately.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Tools > Options > Privacy > History to see if there is an option like `Remember visited pages for at least`. If it is not working, check http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.history_expire_days to see if it helps.

Another way to check is to [start your firefox in safe mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) to disable all plugins to see if there is any plugin that causing this problem.

Comment: I tried that, it still only goes back to mid June in the history, but goes back way further in the address bar.

Comment: So I suppose you can fire a bug for them?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same - I suspect the upgrade from Firefox 13 to 14 as the history dates from the same date as the upgrade on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much user. changing defaults of >> browser.formfill.expire_days. only worked for me after looking for so long. i didnt havnt account just signed up to thank you after seeing only working reply got -1 review. Thank you again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Browsing history and search history are stored separately.

Search history is saved as part of the form history. Form history expiration time is controlled by `about:config` preference `browser.formfill.expire_days` and defaults to 180 days.

Browsing history is controlled by Places management system and its expiration time [is auto-adjusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Places_Expiration):

> Expiration is based on hardware specs, specifically on memory size and CPU cores. This means on mobile and old systems expiration will be more aggressive than on high-end hardware, to try keep the database size at a reasonable (and performant) value.

But is customizable:

> Usually there is no need to tweak or set any preference, since adaptive behavior should satisfy each need, though in case of unexpected issues it's possible to act on some hidden preferences:
>
> - *places.history.expiration.interval_seconds*: Minimum number of seconds between expiration steps. Default is 180 seconds.
> - *places.history.expiration.max_pages*: The maximum number of pages that may be retained in the database before starting to expire. Default value is calculated on startup and put into the *places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages* preference. This transient version of the preference is just mirroring the current value used by expiration, setting it won't have any effect.

Or you can use [Expire history by days](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/) add-on.